# Preg_replace() removing all but the end of query

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pagination

Before everything, sorry for my bad english.

I have this query:

```
SELECT t1.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id_c AND t2.status=1) AS aula 
FROM table_c t1 
WHERE t1.status=1 
AND t1.id IN (SELECT t3.id_c FROM table_cu t3 WHERE t3.id_c=t1.id AND t3.id_u=1) 
AND t1.id IN (SELECT t4.id_c FROM table_cp t4 WHERE t4.id_c=t1.id AND t4.id_p=3) 
LIMIT 0,25
```

This query returns me a set of results, no problems until now, but I have a pagination class with a very basic process: It counts how many entries I got, then it breaks the entries into pieces, then with this values I paginate.

The issue is inside this method in the 'pagination class', here's the code:

```
function total_entries()
{

    $db = new db(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

    $qtdEntries = 0;

    $queryQtd = $this->sql;
    $queryQtd = preg_replace("/SELECT (.*) FROM /sei", "'SELECT COUNT(*) as qtd FROM '", $queryQtd);
    $queryQtd = preg_replace("/ORDER BY (.+)/", "", $queryQtd);
    $queryQtd = preg_replace("/LIMIT (.+)/", "", $queryQtd);

    $resultAll = $db->get_row($queryQtd); //Gets the result, in this case, it returns the number of entries

    if($resultAll){
        $qtdEntries = $resultAll->entries; //Number of entries
    }

    return $qtdEntries;
}
```

Basically when I run this method, the query inside of it returns like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as qtd FROM table_cp t4 WHERE t4.id_c=t1.id AND t4.id_p=3)
```

When it should return something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as qtd FROM table_c t1 WHERE t1.status=1
```

Any ideas how to correct this issue?

Comment: I just don't understand, what you try to do, but maybe [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#idm47375595557216) in combination with the function [FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) can give you a better approach to your pagination goal.

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain: I have that query that I want to count how many rows it returns to me, and, if possible, using something close to what I already have.

Comment: If you're using a `LIMIT` clause then use simply `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in combination with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` If you're not using a `LIMIT` clause then use simply a subselect `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your first query goes here)`. If your query is slow then this (and your) approach will double the problem though.

Comment: Can you post how do I use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()` using the first query of my post, so I can mark your answer as correct? And thanks.

Comment: I had somehow overlooked your original query. The problem you did run into is the greediness of patterns. The pattern matches as much as possible and therefor just into the subselect in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach to this problem is to use MySQLs builtin functionality:

You add simply [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#idm47375595557216) after the `SELECT` key word in combination with the function [FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t1.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id_c AND t2.status=1) AS aula 
FROM table_c t1 
WHERE t1.status=1 
AND t1.id IN (SELECT t3.id_c FROM table_cu t3 WHERE t3.id_c=t1.id AND t3.id_u=1) 
AND t1.id IN (SELECT t4.id_c FROM table_cp t4 WHERE t4.id_c=t1.id AND t4.id_p=3) 
LIMIT 0,25
```

To obtain the count of rows if there were no `LIMIT` clause, you can now use the statement

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

as next query.

The problem with the regexp approach is to get the regexp right. Matching is usually greedy, it will match as much as possible. In this case it will just match right to the last condition of the `WHERE` clause because this condition uses a subselect with the `FROM` key word. Because of that the pattern

```
SELECT (.*) FROM
```

in

```
$queryQtd = preg_replace("/SELECT (.*) FROM /sei", "'SELECT COUNT(*) as qtd FROM '", $queryQtd);
```

matches much more than the field list of the SELECT (that contains a subselect with `FROM` too).