# Get total number of rows when using LIMIT and UNION in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

`Query:`

```
SELECT
    tbl_a.id as aid,
    tbl_a.name as aname,
    null location,
    .....
    .....
    from tbl_a
    .........//left join to fetch some other data
    .........//where condition
UNION ALL
    0 aid,
    null aname,
    tbl_b.location as location,
    .....
    .....
    from tbl_b
    .........//left join to fetch some other data
    .........//where condition
limit '.$recordperpage.' OFFSET '.$offset.'
```

here,`$recordperpage` and `$offset` is dynamic.

now i am trying to fetch all no. of rows without limit.

> exa:
>   No. of rows with limit: 20
>   No. of rows without limit: 50
>   i am trying to fetch no. of rows without limit(means 50).

So how to achive that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really I do not understand what your problem If you want to all record without limit then `remove limit clause`

Comment: The problem is i use pagination, so i have to know what is the total no. of rows?

Comment: Use PHP `count($result_array)` to get number of records

Comment: That contain no. of records within limit. suppose: total records without limit is 50, but using limit is 20, then your method return 20, not 50.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538115/preg-replace-removing-all-but-the-end-of-query

Comment: so you use the same query without limit to bring the total number of records but use count instead of selection and save that in a variable and pass to the pagination may be ajax

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is something for you?
Take a look here.

[How to count all records but only retrieve (LIMIT) a specific number for display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060213/how-to-count-all-records-but-only-retrieve-limit-a-specific-number-for-display)

Answer (score 0):

This query does the trick:

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM
(SELECT
    tbl_a.id as aid,
    tbl_a.name as aname,
    null location,
    .....
    .....
    from tbl_a
    .........//left join to fetch some other data
    .........//where condition
UNION ALL
    0 aid,
    null aname,
    tbl_b.location as location,
    .....
    .....
    from tbl_b
    .........//left join to fetch some other data
    .........//where condition
) union_table
```